# why &(arr+1) does not compile

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

I wrote the next code:

```
int main()
{
    int arr[] = {1,2,3,4,5};

    std::cout <<"&arr: " <<&arr<<"\narr&:"<<&(arr+1);

    return 0;   
}
```

why is &arr compile and gives the address of arr at the position 0, 
and &(arr+1) doesn't compile?
(I have expected it will return the address of arr at the position 1)

Comment: `arr+1` is an rvalue, and doesn't have an address. It doesn't work for the same reason that `&42` doesn't work.

Comment: Did you perhaps mean `std::cout << "arr: " << arr << "\narr: " << (arr+1);`, i.e. print the first and second entry of `arr`?

Comment: @HenriMenke Wouldn't this just print the address?

Comment: Consider `&arr + 1` or `&arr[1]`.

Comment: @Kosta Yes, it will print the address of the first and second element, which is what I think OP is trying to achieve. https://wandbox.org/permlink/RDUMbalOgoovRVps

Comment: Which is it: `c` or `c++`?

Comment: @ScottHunter Use of `std::cout` forces this C++.

Answer (score 4):

`&arr` is not an address "at a position", but the address of the entire array. You can see this via the difference in types:

`&arr` is the address of the array and has type `ARR*`, where `ARR` is the type `int[5]`. When combined, this type looks like `int(*)[5]`.

`&arr[0]` is the address of the first element. It has type `int*`.

Now the actual values are the same because the array object starts at its first element, but it helps to not focus on that when trying to understand arrays vs. pointers.

When you say `arr + 1`, what's actually happening is that `arr` is being silently converted from an array (`int[5]`) to a pointer (`int*`) to the first element of the array. You then advance this pointer by one `int`. This results in an `int*` pointing to the second element of the array. This is the result you wanted to print and is equivalent to `&arr[1]`.

Remember that `&` takes the address of an object. It's meaningless to take the address of a temporary like the pointer `arr + 1`. `&(arr + 1)` is equivalent to `&(&arr[1])`. They both try to take the address of something that logically doesn't have an address of its own. Remember that a pointer can store an address as its *value*, but the only reason `&` comes into play is because you can use it to obtain the address of an object, which can then be stored into a pointer. `&ptr` is the address of `ptr` itself, not the value stored in `ptr`.

---

In short, be consistent with what you want. Both of the following will print the address of the first element and the address of the second element. Both print two `int*`s since your intent is about individual elements, not the whole array:

```
std::cout << "First: " << &arr[0] << "\nSecond: " << &arr[1];
std::cout << "First: " << arr << "\nSecond: " << (arr + 1);
```